# Showing a large form in parts using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an interesting problem that I can't seem to figure out. I have a large form that is shown/hidden to the user in parts using javascript. This works great, but now I need to add the ability to "loop" over certain questions. For example, one question in the form is "What is the gender of your roommate? This question would be asked for as many roommates as the user said they have earlier in the form.

Obviously I won't know how many roommates they have until the script runs, so I don't know how to handle the inputs that are looped back.

I was thinking of dynamically changing the name of the input once the question is looped back, eg.the question would show:

```
<input type="radio" value="male" name="gender[0]" />
<input type="radio" value="female" name="gender[0]" />
```

on the first pass, then when this question gets displayed again, the radios would be:

```
<input type="radio" value="male" name="gender[1]" />
<input type="radio" value="female" name="gender[1]" />
```

I also have to send these values to a script for validation before moving on to the next question. Does anyone have any advice for this?

Comment: What is your question? It looks like you have just solved your problem by changing `[0]` to `[1]`.

Comment: i dont understand your question, what u want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use any JS library (e.g. JQuery) to dynamically add HTML elements and manipulate them.

`n = number of "roommates"`

`roommates_gender_div_id` is the id of the `<div>` where you want to add the radio buttons

```
for(var i=0; i < n; i++){
    $('<input type="radio" value="male" name="gender['+i+']" />').appendTo('#roommates_gender_div_id');

    $('<input type="radio" value="female" name="gender['+i+']" />').appendTo('#roommates_gender_div_id');

}
```

Then you can use any JQuery selector to retrieve all the radio buttons and send it to `validation` function.
Example of selector:

```
    $('#roommates_gender_div_id input:radio')
```